# What is 'Crushed Bones'?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

While playing with a mace based character, I've noticed the proc "Crushed Bones" when hitting a monster with mace skill at level 3.

On the wiki for [mace skill](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Maces_(Skill)) there is no mention of this proc.

While there is a page on [crushed bones](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Crushed_Bones), I don't see that skill in any of my skills.

I am currently at skils:

- Macery 4 (though I saw it at 3 skill 3)
- Bezerker Rage 1
- Flash-shaping 1
- Mathematigic 1
- Magic Training 1
- Smithing 3
- Emomancy 1

(Its a pure random skill set)

Am I just seeing things? or am not seeing something obvious? or is the wiki lacking (I'd rather not be editing the wiki based on my suppositions alone)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to master game file (skillDB.xml), `Crushed Bones` debuff has 8% chances to occur on target hit starting from the skill `Mace Rehearsal` (level 3 of `mace skill`).

Maybe it has been added in a patch or in an extension, explaining the outdated wiki page

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but answering in case of googles.

As of January 2015, crushed bones applies:

-2 burliness
-4 nimbleness
-2 melee pwr
-5 block
-3 armour

Duration 68 turns